# Why we use layout params

Tags: android, layout, parameters

---

> Please tell me  Why we use layoutparams in android studio   Examples
> are:-- Linearlayout.layoutparams Relativelayout.layoutparams

---

Answer (score 1):

Layout Params attributes you can set on a child view to affect its position and size in the containing linear layout.

For Example to set Gravity, Orientation, Position, Weightsum for childs.

You may go through official site of Android Developers [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams) & [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)

Comment: But sir we also use under the xml file.  Like android:gravity, android:textcolor etc.                         And also suggest me how to learn android in efffective manner

Comment: @AnandShukla when you are talking about android:textcolor then there scope is only that Tag in which you are using because Tags containing this property will not have any child.. LayoutParams is applied on layouts ScrollViews etc that can contain childs..

Comment: For learning Android you should go through from different tutorials and also you kay get help from here.. If you have any question you may ask me..